# Can my boyfriends stalker here cause travel visa entry problems when he visits me in US again?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, officials

I live in the US, and have a foreign boyfriend, who has been here several times and never overstayed.

However, he has a stalker in the US, who is acting like **he** is getting stalked.

Could this person cause my boyfriend trouble entering the US?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. As I understand it, your boyfriend is from another country and comes to visit you in the US. And he has a stalker. And that stalker is accusing your boyfriend of stalking him. And you want to know whether that could cause problems at immigration for your boyfriend. Is that right?

Comment: Yes your boyfriends stalker CAN cause problems for him through false accusations and typically if you're convicted of a crime in the USA you become deportable. However you mentioned visa **ENTRY** problems, the problems will typically arise only after he enters and the stalker accuses him.

Comment: @pnuts Contrary to your assertion many people lie to law enforcement about someone stalking them and get away with it especially if it's a woman accusing a man. There is more than abundant documented evidence of that and restraining orders issued against completely innocent parties.

Comment: Although this might be a valid question, I don't think we can reliably answer it on Travel. May I suggest contacting law enforcement agencies and a lawyer?

Comment: How does this stalker even know he's in the US? Your boyfriend should refrain from any social media while he's visiting or put out fake entries that make it appear that he's still at home.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think you need legal advice here not Travel advice. Please contact a lawyer/attorney. They are more likely to help solve your problem than we are.